# Adobe Acrobat Pro Repeating Sections

Tags: acrobat

I am trying to duplicate a section of my PDF form, however I am not sure how to do this in Adobe Acrobat Pro. Has anyone ever done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the fields in the form that you would like to duplicate, right click, and select "Create Multiple Copies."

If you are looking to achieve this programmatically, then we will need some more background about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Many times, in various variations…

Which one would be most suitable for your application depends on the form and the workflow.

Comment: I just want to know how to select a editable form section and add a repeating button to it.